# jQuery use replace() function to add words for string

Tags: jquery, json, replace

I have a special time format from json, ex: **07_23** means **07:00 - 23:00**,and when it shows **24**, ex: **07_24** it should change to **07:00 - 23:59**.

My code is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var json = [{"name":"Meee","time":"07_24"}];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + json[i].time + ":00" + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
    
    $("td:contains('_')").text($("td:contains('_')").text().replace('_', ':00-'));
    $("td:contains('24')").text($("td:contains('24')").text().replace('24:00', '23:59'));
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfdqj6oo/1/)

I think my code is a little bit stupid, are there any best way to remove **07_24** underline, add **:00** for each number, and change **24** to **23:59**? Or can I use regular expression to achieve that goal?

Comment: Just to be clear, there is nothing wrong with your above code correct?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with my code, but I think it's not the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Personally I think your method is fine. I don't think it's a *"stupid"* way to do it.

Comment: Why the hell is everybody there downvoted?

Comment: I don't know why... it shocks me @@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  @Spencer Wieczorek mentioned in comment .. your code is good .. but If you need to simplify it a little bit .. or just need to know another way to doing that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var json = [{"name":"Meee","time":"07_24"}];

        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var Splittime = json[i].time.split('_');
            var all_time = Splittime[0]+':00-'+((Splittime[1] == 24)? '23:59' : Splittime[1]+':00');
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td><td>" + all_time + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xfdqj6oo/3/) another [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xfdqj6oo/4/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xfdqj6oo/2/

```
var formatTime = function(time) {
    return time.split('_').map(function(hour) {
        return hour === '24'? '23:59': hour + ':00';
    }).join('-');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"name":"Meee","time":"07_24"}];

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + formatTime(json[i].time) + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);            
    }
});
```

Basically there is a function to take care of the time formatting/transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a pretty simple regular expression to do this:

```
var new_string = "some string 07_23 bla bla".replace(/([0-2][0-9])_24/g,"$1:00-23:59").replace(/([0-2][0-9])_([0-2][0-9])/g,"$1:00-$2:00");
```

which outputs "bla bla some string 07:00-23:00 bla bla"

Answer (score 0):

You change always the same part so use regular expression is not necessary. Because you just have to change the _ to :00- and the 24:00 to 23:59 it's constant so you dont need regular expression.